# Do event emitters always fire one after the other ,in the order they have been emitted

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

```
var events = require('events');                                                                                                                                                            
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();                                                                                                                                              

var ringBell = function ringBell()                                                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                                                                          
 console.log('ring ring ring');                                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                                                                          

var lockDoor = function lockDoor()                                                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                                                                          
console.log("lock door");                                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                                          

eventEmitter.on("ringBell", ringBell);                                                                                                                                                     
eventEmitter.on("lockDoor", lockDoor);                                                                                                                                                     
eventEmitter.emit('ringBell');                                                                                                                                                             
eventEmitter.emit('lockDoor');
```

So the ringBell event is emitted first followed by the lockDoor Event.

My question is that does ringBell event handler complete first before the lockDoor event is emitted ?

Comment: JS is single threaded - so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In this case yes, but if you were to put something more complex in your event handlers, like an asynchronous db call, then it would start the `lockDoor` event handler before completing the `ringBell` event handler.

Comment: "before completing the ringBell event handler" --- that's wrong. You cannot run the half of an event handler. All `ringBell` handlers are called completely before any `lockDoor` handler. It's guaranteed to be so.

Comment: If the first event handler contains an asynchronous function it won't block execution of the other event handlers. Try putting something like a db read with a promise or a timeout in his `ringBell` event handler (and hold the `console.log` until this completes) and you'll find the that the `lockDoor` `console.log` call is run before the asynchronous code completes and the `ringBell` message is printed.

Comment: It will not be an event emitter handler then. Event handlers are always evaluated **COMPLETELY**. Put the code that demonstrates what you say and I will show you where your statement becomes falsy.

Comment: Most likely will the be called in order but that does necessarily mean they also complete in order - depending on the actual code in `ringBell`.